# Core Data - NSArrayController - ObjectAtIndex

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

I am developing a core data based application, and have a NSTableView bound to an NSArrayController, which is pulling a core data entity.

I need, in code, to be able to pull a specific object from core data, based on a specific row in the table, i had thought this would be trivial by asking the NSArrayController for the object at a specific index. However it appears that the NSArrayController has no methd for this, which i find very odd.

I could setup a fetch request, but that seems very expensive just to fetch a specific object.

So, am i missng something, or is it really this clunky?

Thanks

Gareth

Comment: why can't you use `arrangedObjects` ?

Comment: because i am not trying to find the selected object/objects, this is for custom drawing code, where the function supplies an index, from which i need to pull the correct object to be able to draw some custom text/images into the cell view. Again, unless i am missing something :)

Comment: There's definitely misunderstanding between us... Assuming you have object called `Object`,`- (UITableViewCell*)tableVIew:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {Object *object = self.arrayController.arrangedObjects[indexPath.row]; // do you drawing after.. }` Don't you need something like this?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i was missing, i knew it had to be simpler than it appeared! Post this as an answer and i will accept, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have object (NSManagedObject subclass) called `Object`,

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath*)indexPath 
{
    Object *object = self.arrayController.arrangedObjects[indexPath.row]; 
    // do you drawing, cell setup, etc. after
}
```